# How to pass a reference to a string?

Tags: c

Everything I've read about `scanf`, `gets` and `fgets` is that they are problematic; either with white space, overflow or complexity.  I'm taking an intro to C course and because I have enough experience programming in Java and other languages to feel confident doing so, I decided to create my own function to obtain string input from the user using the `getchar()` function.  The relevant pieces of my code are below:

```
bool get_string (char prompt[], char* string)
{
    printf(prompt); // Prompt the user

    // Ensure string is allocated to store the null character and reset it if it has been initialized
    do { string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); } while (string == NULL);

    int index = 0;
    char place = getchar();
    while (place != '\n') // Obtain all characters before endl
    {
        string = (char*)realloc(string, sizeof(string) + sizeof(char)); // Create room in the array
        if (string == NULL) return false; // Ensure realloc worked correctly
        string[index++] = place; // Place the new string in the second to last index
        place = getchar();
    }
    string[index] = '\0'; // Append the null character at the end

    return true; // Operation succeeded
}
```

Through testing and debugging I'm managed to figure out that:

1. My function meets specification locally, and the parameter `string` holds the entered string.
2. The `char*` pointer I am using in my main method is not being altered.  After calling my input function, the dereference of this pointer remains the same as its initial value.

I was under the impression that because I was passing a pointer to the function it would treat the parameter as by reference.  In fact, this is what I was taught in the class.  Any insight can help.

Bonus points awarded if:

You can tell me why it won't let me free my `char*` pointer in main.  (Maybe because it hasn't been allocated via the same issue?)

What else I am doing wrong, such as calling realloc too many times?

NOTE: I am using the MSVC C89 compiler and define bool, true and false precompile.

Comment: Hmmm `do { string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); } while (string == NULL);`  looks like a potential infinitive loop.  Better to return with an error indication.

Comment: The caller of `bool get_string (char prompt[], char* string)` will never see the value of `string` allocated.  (`string` Pass by value, not by reference)

Comment: `sizeof(string)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `printf(prompt)` is vulnerable to a format string attack. Better to use `printf("%s", prompt)`

Comment: "I was passing a pointer to the function it would treat the parameter as by reference." No.  If the you had `char ls[100]; get_string("Hello", ls);` then code would convert the array `ls` to the address of its first element `&ls[0]` - that is the actual argument.  Then `string` would receive  that and copy it to the formal parameter `string`.  In _effect_, from the caller's point-of-view, it is like pass by reference as `get_string()` affects `ls[]`, but in detail, it is still pass by value (of pointers) `&ls[0]` --> `string`.

Comment: Your proposed solution is a lot more problematic, and just as complex as any of the functions you're trying to replace. All this proves is that you need to spend some time learning a language before you go trying to reinvent it.

Comment: All parameters are passed by value in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The char* pointer I am using in my main method is not being altered. After calling my input function, the dereference of this pointer remains the same as its initial value.

This is something that trips a lot of people up when they first start writing C.  If you want a function to update a parameter that is a *pointer* value, you must pass a pointer to a pointer.

Assume the following:

```
void foo( T *p )
{
  *p = new_value(); // update the thing p is pointing to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T val;
  foo( &val ); // update val
}
```

Pretty straightforward - we want the `foo` function to write a new value to `val`, so we pass a pointer to `val`.  Now replace the type `T` with the type `R *`:

```
void foo( R **p )
{
  *p = new_value(); // update the thing p is pointing to
}

void bar( void )
{
  R *val;
  foo( &val ); // update val
}
```

The semantics are exactly the same - we are writing a new value to `val`.  All that's changed is the types of `val` and `p`.

So, your function prototype needs to be

```
bool get_string (char prompt[], char **string)
```

since you want to modify the *pointer* value that `string` points to.  This also means that in the body of your function, you're writing to `*string`, not `string`.

The preferred method for writing a `malloc` call is

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * number_of_elements );
```

or

```
T *p;
...
p = malloc( sizeof *p * number of elements );
```

The cast is unnecessary as of C89<sup>1</sup>, and under C89 can actually suppress a useful diagnostic.  Since C99 did away with implicit `int` declarations it's not much of an issue anymore, but it's still better to leave it off.  Also notice the operand of `sizeof`; instead of a type expression like `(char)`, we use the expression `*p`.  Since the type of the expression `*p` is `T`, then `sizeof *p` gives the same result as `sizeof (T)`.  Not only does it look cleaner, but it reduces maintenance if you ever decide to change the type of `p`.

In your case, `p` is `*string`, giving us

```
*string = malloc( sizeof **string );
```

Since `realloc` is a potentially expensive operation, you really don't want to call it for every new character.  A better strategy is to initially allocate a buffer that should handle most cases, then extend it by some factor of the current size (such as doubling it) as necessary.  In this case, I'd do something like the following:

```
size_t stringSize = INITIAL_SIZE; // keeps track of the physical buffer size

*string = malloc( sizeof *string * stringSize );
if ( ! *string )
  // initial memory allocation failed, panic

while ((place = getchar()) != '\n' && place != EOF) 
{
   if ( index == stringSize )
   {
     // double the buffer size
     char *tmp = realloc( *string, sizeof **string * ( stringSize * 2 ) );
     if ( tmp )
     {
       *string = tmp;
       stringSize *= 2;
     }
   }
   (*string)[index++] = place; 
}
```

This reduces the total number of calls to `realloc`, which should maximize your performance.

Also, if `realloc` fails, it will return `NULL` and leave the currently allocated buffer in place; however, if that happens, you *really* don't want to assign that result back to `*string`, otherwise you'll lose your only reference to that memory.  You should *always* assign the result of `realloc` to a temporary variable and check it *before* assigning back to `*string`.

Also note how we subscript `*string`; since the subscript `[]` operator has higher precedence than the unary `*` operator, `*string[index++]` will be parsed as `*(string[index++]`), which isn't what we want - we want to index into `*string`, not `string`.  So, we have to explicitly group the `*` operator using parentheses, giving us

```
(*string)[index++] = place;
```

---

<sup>1.  It is necessary in C++, however, but if you're writing C++ you should be using the `new` operator instead.</sup>

Comment: This is an awesome answer, thank you!  I've gotten my code to work and cleaned it up to meet C standards.  My professor explained pointers to pointers, but until now I thought it was legitimately a waste of memory.  Now I understand why it isn't as you add dimensions to your data structures.

Comment: @LukeSamuel: multiple indirection can get hairy in a hurry, and you'll rarely see more than three levels of indirection in actual code (`T ***p`); however, sometimes you can't avoid it.  You can find plenty of derisive comments about "three star programmers" on SO and elsewhere; personally, I think that once you understand the rules you can work with any level of indirection, and to me it's not that intimidating.  I am, however, a crazy person.

Answer (score 3):

> I was under the impression that because I was passing a pointer to the function it would treat the parameter as by reference. In fact, this is what I was taught in the class. Any insight can help.

There are **no** by references in C. Every parameter you pass is *by value*.

Thus:

```
void foo(int a) {
  a = 21;
  // a == 21 for the rest of THIS function
}
void bar(void) {
  int x = 42;
  foo(x);
  // x == 42
}
```

Same goes for:

```
static int john = 21;
static int harry = 42;
void foo(int * a) {
  a = &john;
  // a points to john for the rest of THIS function
}
void bar(void) {
  int * x = &harry;
  foo(x);
  // x still points to harry
}
```

If you wanted to change a pointer via a parameter, then you'd need to pass a pointer to that pointer:

```
static int john = 21;
static int harry = 42;
void foo(int ** m) {
  *m = &john;
}
void bar(void) {
  int * x = &harry;
  foo(&x); // passing the address of x by value
  // x now points to john
}
```

> What else I am doing wrong, such as calling realloc too many times?

```
printf(prompt);
```

Security issue: Try things like `"%s"` as value for `prompt`. Better use `puts` or `printf("%s", prompt)`.

```
do { string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); } while (string == NULL);
```

That's a possible infinite loop. If `malloc` fails, calling it immediately again won't change anything. Also: Do not cast the return value of `malloc`. Moreover is `sizeof(char)` *defined* to be equal to `1`.

```
int index = 0;
```

For indices use `size_t`.

```
char place = getchar();
```

There's a reason `getchar` returns an `int`, namely to be able to check for `EOF`, which you ...

```
while (place != '\n')
```

... don't, but should!

```
string = (char*)realloc(string, sizeof(string) + sizeof(char));
```

Do not cast the return value, `sizeof(string)` is not doing what you think it does, it is a compile time constant (probably `8` on a 64 bit system).

```
if (string == NULL) return false;
```

Memory leak, because...

> If there is not enough memory, the old memory block is not freed and null pointer is returned.
>
> [[Source]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)

---

Here's how I'd read a line in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char * readline(char const * const prompt) {
  char buffer[10];
  char * string = malloc(1);
  if (string == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  // The accumulated length of the already read input string.
  // This could be computed using strlen, but remembering it
  // in a separate variable is better, performancewise.
  size_t accumLength = 0;
  string[0] = '\0';
  printf("%s", prompt);
  while (fgets(buffer, 10, stdin) != NULL) {
    // To see what has been read in this iteration:
    // printf("READ: |%s|\n", buffer);
    // Compute the length of the new chunk that has been read:
    size_t const newChunkLength = strlen(buffer);
    // Try to enlarge the string so that the new chunk can be appended:
    char * const newString = realloc(string, accumLength + newChunkLength + 1);
    if (newString == NULL) {
      free(string);
      return NULL;
    }
    string = newString;
    // Append the new chunk:
    strcpy(string + accumLength, buffer);
    accumLength += newChunkLength;
    // Done if the last character was a newline character
    assert(accumLength > 0);
    if (string[accumLength - 1] == '\n') {
      // NOTE: Wasting 1 char, possible solution: realloc.
      string[accumLength - 1] = '\0';
      return string;
    }
  }
  // EOF is not an error!
  if (feof(stdin)) {
    return string;
  }
  free(string);
  return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  char const * const input = readline(">");
  printf("---\n%s\n---\n", input);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A OP wants to "pass a reference to a string", then pass to the function the address of where to store the address of the first element of the string.

```
// The function signature needs some changes
// 1: string read.  0: out-of-memory  EOF:end-of-file
//               const                     *
int get_string(const char prompt[], char** string) {

  // Never do this.  If prompt contain `'%'`, code becomes a hackers target
  // printf(prompt); // Prompt the user

  fputs(prompt, stdout); // Prompt the user
  fflush(stdout);

  // use size_t, not int
  // int index
  size_t size = 0;  // Keep track of size
  for (;;) {
    // Use int to distinguish EOF from all other char
    // char place = getchar();
    int place = getchar();
    // Note: reallocating every loop is generally inefficient
    void *former = *string;

     // sizeof(string) + sizeof(char)
     // sizeof(string) is the size of the pointer, not the size of memory it points to.
     // sizeof(char) is always 1
    *string = realloc(*string, size + 1);
    if (*string == NULL) {
      free(former);  // free old buffer
      return 0; // fail
    }
    // add termination on \n or EOF
    if (place == '\n' || place == EOF) {
      // Add detection and housekeeping for EOF
      if (place == EOF && size == 0) {
        free(*string);
        *string = NULL;
        return EOF;
      }
      break;
    }
    (*string)[size++] = place;
  }
  (*string)[size] = `\0`;
  return 1; // Operation succeeded
}
```

usage

```
char *s = NULL;
while (get_string("Hello ", &s) > 0) {
  puts(s);
}
free(s);
s = NULL;
```