# C Program to print first and last n lines in a file, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, file, fgets, tail, fseek

I am new to programming in general. Please note that this is for homework.
I am using a txt file with a-z in lowercase.
I use the command `./a.out test.txt` to run the program, then enter a number.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void cat(FILE *fp, int num) {
    int count = 0;
    char buffer[4096];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0) {
        if (count == num)
            break;
        else
            count++;
        fputs(buffer, stdout);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num, count = 0;
    long length;
    char buffer[4096];

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open this file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    scanf("%d", &num);
    cat(fp, num);
    printf("...\n");

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, (length - 2), SEEK_SET);
    printf("1\n");
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0) {
        fputs(buffer, stdout);
    }
    if (ftell(fp) == '\n') {
        count++;
        length = ftell(fp);
        fseek(fp, (length - 4), SEEK_SET);
        printf("2\n");
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0) {
            fputs(buffer, stdout);
        }
    } else {  //<------ missing opening brace
        length = ftell(fp);
        fseek(fp, (length - 2), SEEK_SET);
        printf("3\n");
        while (fgets(buffer,s izeof(buffer), fp) != 0) {
            fputs(buffer, stdout);
        }
        if (count == num) {
            printf("4\n");
            while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0) {
                fputs(buffer, stdout);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: Please add white space between operators your code is hard to read, and what is this `ftell(fp)=='\n'`? why are you doing that?

Comment: You posted code that did not compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformatted your code to improve readability.  There is a missing `{` where I indicated.  As posted, the code does not compile.

Your program should be able to print the first `n` lines, but your method cannot work for the last `n` lines.

Allocate an array of `n` buffers:

```
char (*array)[4096] = calloc(4096, num);
```

For each line read, move the buffers and copy the line at the last position:

```
memmove(array[0], array[1], sizeof(array[0] * (num - 1));
strcpy(array[num - 1], buffer);
```

There are more efficient methods but you should be able to implement this simple method.

When you reach the end of file, print the non empty lines from the array.

**EDIT:**

Here is a complete version that uses an array of `num+1` buffers.  It reads the whole file, printing the first `num` lines as they are read, and keeping the last `num` lines in the array at all times, cycling the position at which it read the next line over `num+1` buffers.

At the end of file, if the file has at more than `num` lines, extra lines must be printed, potentially separated by a `--------` if lines are skipped in the middle of the file. The last `num` lines or less are printed: `pos` is computed to find the proper buffer modulo `num+1` and the lines are printed until the last.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num, pos, count;
    FILE *fp;
    char (*array)[4096];  /* pointer to an array of buffers */

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage headtail filename [number]\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        /* get the number from the command line if 2 args were given */
        if (sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &num) != 1) {
            num = -1;
        }
    } else {
        /* otherwise read from standard input */
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {
            num = -1;
        }
    }
    if (num < 0) {
        printf("Invalid number\n");  /* negative or non numeric */
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate space for num+1 buffers */
    array = malloc(4096 * (num + 1));

    for (count = pos = 0; fgets(array[pos], 4096, fp) != NULL; count++) {
        /* printing the first num lines */
        if (count < num)
            fputs(array[pos], stdout);
        /* cycle buffers for num lines + 1 extra buffer */
        if (++pos >= num + 1)
            pos = 0;
    }
    if (count > num) {
        /* more lines to print */
        pos = count - num;
        if (pos > num) {
            /* print place holder for missing lines */
            printf("...\n");
        } else {
            /* print from the last line printed */
            pos = num;
        }
        for (; pos < count; pos++) {
            fputs(array[pos % (num + 1)], stdout);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? As I've stated above, I don't really know much about programming, so could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now I just need to understand it... :P

Comment: @N.Cvt.: I updated the answer with a simpler and more efficient method that uses less memory.  Study this one, it should be easier to understand.

Comment: Nice! Instead of allocating a large buffer (part) for each line it would be better though to dynamically allocate a separate (correctly sized) buffer for each line. I'm shamelessly adding a link to one of my answers with such a "read line" function for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35351987/1116364

Comment: @DanielJour: Thanks for the alternatie.  Actually, it may not be as efficient: if the file is long, my method just reads the file into the circular buffer list.  Your method, using `getline()` would keep freeing the older lines and laboriously allocate a new one for each line read.  Your method has the advantage of supporting overlong lines but uses a very inefficient reallocation scheme by chunks of 9 bytes.  You should at least make the temporary buffer 1024 bytes long.

Comment: Indeed, the chunk size as well as the chunk size scaling (if added) should be improved. What I was concerned with is wasting space if the lines aren't that long (4095) and if n is large.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! I'll be sure to memorize it!

Answer (score 0):

1) You should check if the file size is less than size of buffer.

2) If you intend to read the file for n lines in chunks of data at a time, read it one line at a time. probably using fscanf. This way you can keep track of how many lines you've read/printed. Also this helps to know whether your file has enough lines at all.