# Difficulty in reading in a DNA sequence file using C code

Tags: c, arrays, file, io, dna-sequence

I am currently taking Coursera Bioinformatics course, and doing the programming assignments. Being, a first year undergraduate just learning C, while I am aware that python is the language that's becoming much more popular for bioinformatics, I am challenging myself to implement every single algorithm in the course in the C language to master it, as it will also benefit me in all my CS courses here, which use C/C++ a lot.

In working on one of the assignments, our goal is to write a program that can take in a shorter DNA pattern and compare it with a long complete DNA strand, and the output the count, which is the number of times the shorter DNA pattern appears in the long complete DNA strand. We are given a file consisting of all the inputs we need, and the gold output, but I am having great trouble in parsing the file properly, even though I've consulted my textbook and numerous documentation. I actually have no problem implementing the algorithm itself; I tested it using smaller hardcoded character arrays in the program itself.

The input file is as follows:

```
Input
TAACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTCCGCATCGAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCGTAGCCTTTCGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTAGTCGATGTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCAGCCTTTAGTAGGCAAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCGAGCCTTTCTCGCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGGTGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCGCAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTCTTGTTTGAATGGCAAGAGCCTTTTCGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAAAAGCCTTTCGTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATCGAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTTATGCAAAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCATTGACAAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCTCAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTGTCGAGCCTTTTTTCAGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTACGAGCCTTTGCAAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCCAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCTTTAGCCTTTCATGGGATAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATTAAGCCTTTTTTATCAAGCCTTTGTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTAGGAGCCTTTGTATAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTCTACAGTAAAGCCTTTTTTGGTCAGCCTTTCTAGCCTTTGATAGCCTTTCTGAAGCCTTTGGCGGAGCCTTTCTGTTAACAGCCCAGCCTTTCTCATAGCCTTTGCGGTATCAGCCTTTGCAGCCTTTCTGGAGCGATAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCCGAGCCTTTTTCAGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCCGAGCCTTTTCAGCCTTTACAGCCTTTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCACAGCCTTTGAGCTAGCCTTTAAGTTAAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTACATTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTTCAGCCTTTAGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCTGAAGCCTTTAGTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCGAAGCCTTTCTGGTGCAACAAGTGAAGCCTTTGCCCTAGCCTTTGCTAGCCTTTCCGAGCCTTTGTCGATATAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGAAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCTAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCCCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATCCTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCCAGAAGCAGCCTTTTGATCAGAGCCTTTCTTCGGACTGCTCCCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGTGTAGCCTTTCTAGCCTTTACGAGCCTTTGCCCAGCCTTTCCCAGCCTTTGAGAGCCTTTACCATATAGCCTTTACATAAGCCTTTGATGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTACTCCAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTATATAGCCTTTCCTGTTAGGCCGTCGGTGCAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTGCTAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTACAGCCTTTTACCGAGCCTTTCCATCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATATCTCTGATCGGGTAGCCTTTCGGCTAGCCTTTGGTAGCCTTTTTCAGCCTTTATGTAAAGCCTTTGTAGCCTTTGATGTGAGCCTTTAGAAGCCTTTGTCAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTTAAGCCTTTTACAAGCCTTTACTCAGAGCCTTTACGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTGCAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTTGATGAGCCTTTGCGGAGCCTTTTCTTTCAGCCTTTTGGCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGTACAGCCTTTTTGAGCACAGCCTTTCGCGAAAGAGCCTTTATCAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTGCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGTATCTGTCTATCATCGAGCCTTTCTAAGCCTTTGCGGAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGTCAGCCTTTCAAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTATTCAAGCCTTTGAACCATAGCCTTTGGCAGCCTTTCAAGCCTTTGACGACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCATTAGCCTTTTAGGAGGCTCATCCGTCTAGCCTTTAAATAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAAGCCTTTGAGAGCCTTTAAAGCCTTTAAACCAAGCCTTTGCGAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGAGCCTTTTGTAGCCTTTTGGAGAGCCTTTGGGCAAGCCTTTAGTATAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTGGCACAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTCAGGAGCCTTTATTGGTGAGCCTTTAGTATAGCCTTTTCAGCCTTTGGCAGCCTTTAATGAAAGCCTTTGCTCAGCCTTTTTCAGCCTTTACAGCCTTTCAAGCCTTTAGCCACAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTGCGAGCCTTTGTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTTCAAGCCTTTTCAGCCTTTCAAAGCCTTTCAAGCCTTTGAAGCCTTTCTAAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGTTCCTAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTTAGGCAGCCTTTCAGAGCCTTTTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGAAAGAGCCTTTAGCCCAGCCTTTTGATTAGCCTTTAGGGAACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAAGCCTTTGGTATACAATCAACGCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTTGGAGCCTTTCAGACTGATCCCAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCTCAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTCTCCAAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTTCGAGCCTTTAGTGAGCCTTTTGAAGCCTTTGTTTAGCCTTTTGTATAGGGTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCCGGAAGCCTTTTGTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTTGTCCGGGAAAGCCTTTGTAAGCCTTTAATGCAGCCTTTCCTATAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTTGGAGCCTTTTCTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGCCAGCCTTTCTCCCGAGCAGCCTTTTAGAAAAAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTTACCGTGGACAGCCTTTCACGAGCCTTTACAGGCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCTAGCCTTTTCCCAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTCTAAGTTCTACGCTTGGGCTAAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTTGCAGCCTTTATATAACTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTTATATCCCTTAAGCCTTTGTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTACGAGGAAAGCCTTTCATGCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTATGAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCACCAGCCTTTCCAGATGCACAAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGAGCCTTTGGCTTATAGCCTTTCATCAGCCTTTCTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCGAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTTAGCCTTTAGCTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATCTAACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAAGCCTTTATGTCCAATTCTAACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAAGCCTTTGCAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTGAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGTCAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCAGCCTTTAGTACGCCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGTATAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCCACTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGAGGAGCGATAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGAAAGCCTTTGTTGCTGCTAGCCTTTGGGTTCTCAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTGTAGCCTTTTACATAGGATTGATTCAAAAGCCTTTTTGAGCCTTTCTGCATTAGCCTTTTCCTCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGAGCCTTTAGATAGCCTTTCGCGACAGCCTTTTGTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCCTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCCAAAGCCTTTGACAGGGTGTAGCCTTTCTAGCCTTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAACTTAAGCCTTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAACCCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTTAGAAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGGAGCCTTTCAGATCTCAGCCTTTTCGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTTCAGAAAAGTAGCCTTTTTAGCAGCCTTTTAAAGCCTTTGGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGTAGCCTTTTCCCAAAAGCCTTTACAGCCTTTGTGAGCCTTTTAGTTCGTTTGAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTTGCGAGAAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTGACGTTCTAGAGCCTTTGGAGCCTTTCACGCGAGCCTTTCAAGCCTTTGACTCCGCAGCCTTTTCGCGACCAGCCTTTGCCGTGCCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAACACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGGGCCGCAGAGCCTTTGAGTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCTAGCCTTTGCAGCCTTTGTCTAGGTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTTGGAAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGCGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTACCCAGCCTTTACGGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCCCATAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCAAATCTAAGCCTTTCGCATATATGGTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATGGTCCTTCAGTTTGAGCCTTTTAGAGCCTTTAAAGGAGCCTTTGTAAGACGAAGGTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCCAGCCTTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAAAAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCTCCTAGCCTTTCATAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGGAGGTCAGCCTTTATGTTAAAGCCTTTAGTTCCCAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTGAAGCCTTTTGTAGCCTTTGCCCGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCCCAACCCTGATCCGTAGCCTTTGGGCTGATCCTGAGCCTTTTCAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAACAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTAGCCAGCCTTTGCAGCCTTTCAGTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCTAGCCTTTCTTGGAGCCTTTCCCAGCCTTTAAGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCGTAGCCTTTGACCATTGTCAGCCTTTCTACTGAGCCTTTCATAGCCTTTTTTAGCCTTTCTAGCAGCCTTTGGAGCCTTTAGAAGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAACACAAGCCTTTATCTGGGCCGCGAGCCTTTTCAACCTAACTACAGCCTTTCTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTACCGAGCCTTTGCGGGAAGCCTTTAAAGAGCCTTTAGAAAAAGCCTTTGGGATAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTTTAGCCTTTTCCTCAAGATTTAGCCTTTGATGAAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCATTGAGCCTTTTAAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTTCTCATCAGCCTTTCACAGCCTTTCTACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGGAGCCTTTTCGCCCCGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTGTAGCCTTTAGAGCCTTTGCTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGTAGCCTTTAGATAGCCTTTTCTGGGAGCCTTTACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAAAGCCTTTCCCCAAAGCCTTTGTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTACAGTCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAAGCCTTTACCTTAGCCTTTGGCAGCCTTTCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTATAAAAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTACCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTTATCGGAAAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGGCAAAGCCTTTTTGCAGCCTTTGGAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTTCAAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCACGTATTAGGAAGCCTTTTACTCTAAGCCTTTATCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTACGGTCAGCCTTTGGTAGCCTTTTCAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAAGAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCCTAGCCTTTCAAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCGAAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATGGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCGGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTACAGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAAGCCTTTTGCAGCCTTTCAAAGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTACGGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTCTCACTAGCCTTTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTATGACGAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTGTCGTGACCTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTACAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCTTAAAAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTTTGAGCCTTTACAGCCTTTCGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCCCAGCCTTTGAAGCCTTTTGGACAGAGCCTTTGCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTACTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTATGGATAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGAGCCTTTGCCTAGCCTTTGAAGCCTTTTTAGCCTTTAACGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGAGCCTTTCTCAGCCTTTGTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGAGCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTGCCCCGAGCACGTAGCCTTTACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTACAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAAAGCCTTTTGAAGAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCTTACTAGCCTTTGCAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCCGAGCCTTTGATAGCCTTTGTCGGTAAGCCTTTGTAGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTGGTAAAGAGCCTTTTCAACAGCCTTTCGGAGCCTTTCGCTACAAGCCTTTTGGCCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCAAGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGCAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCGTTATCTAAGCCTTTACTCCATAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGTCAGTCGAGCCTTTGTTCTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTGTTTGTGGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAATACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCTAGCCTTTCAGCAGCCTTTGTAGCCTTTGAACCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTTCCTTAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTTAGTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCACCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTGAACAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTGACGATATGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTGTAGCCTTTTTTAGCCTTTGAACAGCCTTTGGAGTCAAGCCTTTACGCAGCCTTTCCAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGGTCAGCCTTTTCAGAGCCTTTGCGGTTAGCCTTTGAATAGCCTTTAAAGCCTTTCTCAGCCTTTGTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTGTGAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCCGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCCTACGGAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGCTATCAGCTTGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGTAGCAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTCTCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATCCGAGCCTTTACCAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTATACGTAGCTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGAGCCTTTACCCTGTACCAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTCTCGTGAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTCGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTTTGTGTGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGGGGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTTCAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTAAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGGTAGCAAGCCTTTCGTTATAGCCTTTTATAAGCCTTTTTTAATGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGTAGCCTTTTGATATTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCCCCGAGCCTTTGTTAGAGCCTTTGCAGCCTTTGGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTCGGAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGGGACAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAAGCCTTTTGCAGCCTTTAAGATAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTTCAGCCTTTACAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTTGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTGTTGCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTTGGACAGCCTTTCTGAGCCTTTCGTAGCCTTTACCGCAAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTGAAGAGGAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTCAGAAGCCTTTTAAGCCTTTTCGCAGCCTTTTATCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAGCCTTTACAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTATCAAGCCTTTCTAGCCTTTGAGCCTTTGTGAGCCTTTGTGTCAGCCTTTCAAGCCTTTTTAAGTACAGCCTTTACTCAGCCTTTATAGCCTTTGTCGTAAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTGAAAAGCCTTTACGCACAGACAAGTAGCCTTTCAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTGAGTATGTCCTTGAGCCTTTAAAAGAGCCTTTGGTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTAGCCTTTTATAGCCTTTAAGCCTTTAAGCCTTT
AGCCTTTAG
Output
294
```

First line is the string "Input"

Second line is entire DNA sequence (which as the label "Input" implies, is my input DNA sequence, and which I will refer to it throughout as *text*)

Third line the shorter DNA sequence, which I will refer to as *pattern*.

Fourth line is string "Output"

Fifth line is the gold output, the number of counts which my program should be returning.

I tried parsing the file with the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(argc>1)
  {
    FILE * dataset = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(dataset==NULL)
    {
      printf("File count not be opened or found!\n");
      return 1;
    }
    char  in_label[1000], dna_text[10000], dna_pattern[1000], out_label[1000];
    int  count=0;

    fscanf(dataset, "%s, %s, %s, %s, %d", in_label, dna_text,dna_pattern, out_label,&count);

... and other code below that calls the counting algorithm which I won't show here ...
```

While my call to fscanf does return me in_label correctly, it does not work for the remaining arguments. Basically when I printf out each of my in_label, dna_text, dna_pattern, out_label and count, only in_label correctly gives me the string Input, but the rest all are garbage. I'm really confused, because I thought that the fscanf function automatically skips linefeeds or spaces when reading in from the stream. So why did Input get correctly read into in_label, but not the others???

Also a second question I have is about one shortcoming that I'm aware of in my program, which are the hardcoded array sizes. I know about malloc function, and just learnt about it this week in class, but I just can't figure out how to use it here. Because in order to use malloc, we need to be able to at least "soft code" the size of our array in advance, and here, I just can't imagine how I would be able to tell the compiler, in any "soft coded" manner, what my array sizes will be especially for the dna_text array, which varies greatly from dataset to dataset.

C is really challenging, a world away from python whose convenience I've been so spoilt by. I would greatly appreciate any help to overcome this issue, so that I can move on with my learning of bioinformatics. Thank you very much!

Comment: `"%s, %s, %s, %s, %d"` That format specifier tells `fscanf` too look for commas in your input. So obviously not right. Remove the commas from that specifier. Also, always check the return value of `fscanf`. You'll find it is `1` in your case meaning it was only able to match one input.

Comment: You can read in the DNA sequence in small chunks to the stepping stone string. If your main DNA string (obtained by `malloc`) is not long enough to concatenate it to, then you `realloc` it, keeping track of its length. To do this you will have to read each line separately anyway. I suggest using `fgets` (which retains the `newline`, if it reached it).

Comment: At the bottom of my answer here I have a function to read an arbitrary long line: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35351987/1116364 (It's not perfect, as the scaling of the buffer could be done much better, but should give you an idea).

Comment: @kaylum thank you for your help! after removing the commas, it works! My next question following up would be then, if we are parsing a CSV file, then would the right thing to do to be to put the commas in the format specifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use fstat() to get the file size and malloc() for allocating proper buffers
2. Use fgets() for reading text files line by line. Do not use fscanf() at all.
3. Never read a file at once as you should never know what exactly went wrong if your reading API returned an error. My experience tells me that reading line-by-line is the best strategy when working with text files. Just be sure you have a buffer large enough for storing the longest possible line.

Comment: Thank you! So when using fgets(), does each line that is read in from the file, no matter how long, get converted into a string? Also, how do we know how large our buffer is? Do we have to allocate size for a buffer? Or is it when we are allocating with malloc, we are allocating size on the buffer? I thought malloc allocates on the heap?

Comment: Also I took a look at the documentation for fstat(), while it does provide the information it doesn't seem to give enough fine grained info...it just provides the total size of the file...

Comment: 1. fgets() creats a C NULL-terminated string if the buffer is big enough
2. fstat() gives you the size of the file in bytes. You need nothing more for this task
4. A string cannot be greater that the whole file. Meaning that making the input buffer large enough to hold the whole file is good enough for this task
3. malloc() allocates memory from the heap